# Headphones with 8 ohm speaker

Tags: speakers, mp3

How can I build headphones that could play music and fit into a 4mm headphone jack?

An example of this would be the headphones that come with an iPod.

Comment: Headphones that *play* music? - and what is "4mm inch"?

Comment: @MikeJ-UK the 4mm headphone jack that headphones are plugged into. And I am attempting to play music through the headphones

Comment: @Coder404 mm and inch are 2 different units of measure, you can't use both together like that.

Comment: @Kellenjb fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buy the various parts (connector, wire, transducers) and connect them; but you will find it hard to compete with an overmolded solution for durability and impossible to compete with the price of a premade solution.

If you had an extremely custom requirement perhaps it would be worthwhile, but you might still be better off modifying a purchased pair and changing only what you needed to.

Comment: ok thanks. What kinds of parts would I need? I am using this for a custom solution

Comment: Connectors, wire, and transducers.  Suggest you buy the cheapest pair your can find and take them apart to examine - you will likely decide in the end not to make them yourself.